# Python file opens up in browser window instead of download prompt

Tags: python, html, web, download, server

I am trying to make files downloadable from my website, but when I test it by clicking on the download file, it opens up the code in a webpage, instead of downloading it. I'm using Firefox, by the way.

```
<a href="currentage.py">Age calculator I made, where you plug in your birth year.</a>
```

I know I'm probably doing something very stupid, but the tutorials told me to do this.

Comment: I think you should change your browser's settings to download this type of file in default instead of opening it.

Comment: I don't know what library you are using, but in case of `webdriver`, you can do it via code as it's been explained [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IN HTML5 `download` will do the trick

```
<a href="currentage.py" download>Age calculator I made, where you plug in your birth year.</a>
```